# What does “bitte sehen” mean?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context, listening-comprehension

When leaving a small shop in Germany, the storekeeper said “bitte sehen” to me as I was leaving.

1. What does this mean?
2. What would an appropriate response be? Could I reply by repeating “bitte sehen”?

Comment: Are you sure he didn't say (Auf) "Wiedersehen"? If so, that's an appropriate greeting (See you again), and "Auf Wiedersehen" an appropriate reply.

Comment: That would make a lot of sense, and would explain why google turned up zero results for "bitte sehen". It's quite likely that she said "Wiedersehen" and I misheard. I'll accept that as the correct answer if "bitte sehen" has no meaning in this context (or at all).

Comment: The question resulted from a misunderstanding, which is off-topic imho.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: Resulting from a misunderstanding/question does not make the question off-topic per se (at least in my opinion – the [respective meta question](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/q/655/2594) is only about typos anyway). In particular, if the misunderstanding causing the question is of general interest (as for example it is about a common phrase like this question), I do not think we should close it. Compare for example to the many questions we have originating from a grammatical misconception.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft There are certainly common ("important") misunderstandings that need to be cleared, and I welcome them to be cleared here, though this is hardly one of them. Mostly because it's a random cacophony. Btw, the question doesn't show any research effort.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: I fail to see any “random cacophony”. Yes, research effort is not indicated, but we all know what the result would have been. And that’s only relevant if you want to treat this as a translation question, which it did not really turn out to be, though it started as such.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft There are hundreds of common phrases, which can be misheard in hundreds of different ways, and if this SE grows big one day, you really don't want to be the one sheltering the top 500 German cacophonies. Every cacophony/mondegreen is somewhat random (it's answer thus ob), which can be seen from the answers: *auf wiedersehen* is just as likely to have been intended as *bitte sehr*, and as no further details were provided, the shopkeeper could be Asian and have actually meant *please look at this*, or the shopkeeper could have said something completely else, and so on... whatever...

Comment: @Grantwalzer In defense of my question, I spent a while on google looking at all phrases starting with "bitte", and I did not come across the one I thought I had heard. Additionally, I knew that literally "bitten sehen" means something like "please see", but that didn't fit the situation. Within a few minutes of posting my question on here, I received the correct answer ("Auf Wiedersehen"). In my mind, this stackexchange served it purpose perfectly: it helped me determine what it was I had heard.

Comment: I hope you know this is nothing personal. I just like to have discussions of historical importance.

Comment: @Grantwalzer yes absolutely, thanks :) The usefullness of my question to others in the future is definitely up for debate, as it's possible that it's very rare to mishear someone in the exact way I did. I just wanted to say that for me, personally, I was glad to figure out what I had heard.

Comment: @Grantwalzer: I do not think that there is any risk that we will once be overrun with such questions. Otherwise we would already have more of them by now. (Also, I think you are misusing the word *cacophony.)*

Comment: In which region was the shop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment above, I think the shop-keeper acctually said "(Auf) Wiedersehen"? That's an appropriate farewell (See you again), and "Auf Wiedersehen" an appropriate reply.

Comment: To note, I have since determined that people are also saying "Wiederschauen". This is used in Bavaria as an alternative to "Wiedersehen".

Comment: The same is true for Austria.

Answer (score 17):

Most likely he said "bitteschön". Depending on the context this can have two meanings:

1. "You're welcome" as an reply to "Danke." In this case you aren't expected to answer.
2. "Here you are" when he opens the door for you or gives something. In this case you reply "Danke.".

Comment: Or "bitte sehr". I can imagine that the word ending _-r_ and _-en_ are misunderstood; but I cannot (so easily) imagine that a starting _sch-_ is mistaken for a _s-_.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, what the shop keeper probably said was "Bitte sehr", which is simply another way to say "You're quite welcome" or "Here you are" as Florian mentioned.  This does not necessarily require you to prompt him by saying "Danke".

Comment: He would not have said that "as the customer was leaving", though.

Answer (score 0):

What he meant was *please come again bitte schön.*

I was in Germany for 2 years. When you go into a restaurant, they will say *bitte* like *please* and you say *danke* and then when you're leaving you say *Danke* and they say *bitte*.

It all makes sense when you're there.

Answer (score -4):

*Bitte* is *please* and also *you’re welcome*.

*Sehen* as you spelt it was short for *Wiedersehen*.

I’ve noticed here in Austria they sometimes put words together.

So the shopkeeper was saying “You’re welcome and goodbye” in one word.

Just nod, smile and wave casually to acknowledge him.